# "copy to tmp table" for 24 hours, then timeout; when ALTERing to add PK & AI

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I downloaded the Wiktionary XML dump, and ran `mwdumper.jar` to insert the data into MySQL.

Following the advice in the manual, I commented out the `PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT` part of the `CREATE TABLE` statements, for `page`, `revision` and `text` (which have millions of rows in each, and very large `BLOB`'s); in order to aid in a much faster import time.

After the data had been inserted, I ran the `CREATE INDEX` statements, and these executed fine (in ~30 seconds each).

My problem is, I'm now trying to add the PK's in, and just on the first line, it ran for 86,400 seconds (24 hours), then timed out!

`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` shows *State: copy to tmp table*.

Here are the queries I'm trying to run - it's stuck on the first one:

```
ALTER TABLE revision MODIFY COLUMN rev_id int unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE text MODIFY COLUMN old_id int unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE page MODIFY COLUMN page_id int unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

When I ran `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` while the query was running, the `Handler_read_rnd_next` variable *was* increasing, and there were no other connected users or applications running on the db, to otherwise influence that var.

How can I speed this query up? It's running on a quad-core 3.5GHz development machine with 16GB of RAM, but it's barely using any of this power.

The only options that have been changed from the default install are:

```
max_allowed_packet = 1G
innodb_log_file_size = 100M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 100M
```

And in MySQL Workbench:

[image]

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: If you need to do this multiple times get an SSD.

Comment: @MaxVernon I only need to do this once... btw, it's still running; it's about 12 hours in!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's nothing to be done at this stage. You can't terminate the process (rather, you shouldn't) while running. You cannot modify major memory settings without restarting MySQL.

I, for one, am not enthusiast about loading all table data then loading indexes. However, doing this for the `PRIMARY KEY` is plain wrong. The advice you read related to secondary indexes. With adding a `PRIMARY KEY` InnoDB will rebuild your entire table all over again; so I'm afraid your entire first load step was redundant.

Nevertheless 7 hours for PK compared to 30 seconds for secondary index does not make sense. What is your `innodb_buffer_pool_size`? Which disks? RAID? Which file system?

Comment: The query actually timed out after 24 hours, whilst still in the same state. `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M`. The disk is a single non-RAIDed 1TB 5,400RPM SATA drive running NTFS, with just a few gigs of free space.

Comment: I've now dropped the database, and have re-created it with the `PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT` statements intact. I'm now trying to load the data in, and it is **dramatically** slower, but at least it will work. Any other suggestions appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: To put it into perspective, it's now doing ~100 inserts/sec. It *was* doing ~15,000/sec.

Comment: Well, if this is a MySQL dedicated machine, you'll want to set `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10G` give or take.

Comment: Also, set `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2`, at least for the duration of the process.
Consider killing the query now and run again with larger buffer as mentioned. Note that killing an InnoDB `ALTER TABLE` can make InnoDB upset afterwards, though not corrupted. But you may get nagging messages about missing tables in tablespace.

Comment: So now it's doing ~400/sec. Better! It's still only using <5% of my CPU and barely no RAM though. Is there any way I can make it use more power? I've already set the processes to *Priority: High*. Are there any other vars you'd suggest to change?

Comment: Ahhh, I just noticed something: *`innobase_buffer_pool_size` can't be over 4GB on 32-bit systems*. It was resetting it to 16M! Not sure why it's installed as x86 in the first place, but going to try 4GB for now.

Comment: Hmmm, this is strange: *Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool*... but the system has 16GB of RAM, with only 20% of it in use, currently. I *am* able to use `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G`, but not `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G`. Odd! Anyway, with 1GB of memory allocated, it's now doing ~4000/sec; awesome! Do you have any suggestions for how to fix the error so I can increase it?

Comment: From Googling, after reading pages of results, I found someone else with the same issue: http://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=39677

Comment: You may be able to squeeze as much as 1.3G on x86. To fix the error you should upgrade OS to 64 bit.